# Setting up adb for user access

Tags: adb

I recently purchased an Android phone (my first). This is probably not relevant to the question, but it is a Micromax Canvas Hue AQ5000, running Android 4.4.2.

I want to access the phone from my computer, currently running Debian wheezy. ADB was recommended to me. I installed `android-tools-adb`, and after enabling [Developer Options and USB Debugging](http://www.syncios.com/blog/enable-developer-optionsusb-debugging-mode-on-devices-with-android-4-2-jelly-bean/), I was able to access the phone via `adb shell`, for example.

However, ADB does not work as user. Here is the corresponding udev file, `/lib/udev/rules.d/70-android-tools-adb.rules`.

```
# Set ACLs for console users on adb USB devices
# d001 recovery
# d002 system

ACTION=="add|change", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", \
  ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1", ATTRS{idProduct}=="d001|d002", \
  TAG+="uaccess"
```

How should I modify this file in order to give user access? The natural way seems to be to give access to a group. Along those lines, here is one suggestion,namely [an answer to "Android Debug Bridge (adb) device - no permissions"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18033042/) which suggests

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

So, should I add `GROUP="plugdev"` to that file above, or is there a better way? Also what does the `ATTRS{idVendor}=="18d1"` part mean, and would that work for any device? Also, what does  `ATTRS{idProduct}=="d001|d002"` mean?

I'll consider forwarding good suggestions to the Debian Bug Tracker.

Comment: Why not just run adb as root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my gentoo system, the following udev rules are setup (in `/lib64/udev/rules.d` for me):

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="22b8", MODE="0664", GROUP="android"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0664", GROUP="android"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0664", GROUP="android"
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0664", GROUP="android"
```

These rules give access to USB android devices (22b8 = Motorola, 0bb4 = HTC, 04e8 = Samsung and 18d1 = Google) to anyone in the `android` group.

The name of the group you decide to use is unimportant as long as your user is a member of that group.

---

To address your other questions on the USB identifers, the vendor and product ids identify specific devices.  You can see your identifiers using `dmesg` or `lsusb`.  E.g. when I plug in my phone, `dmesg` reports:

```
[ 4573.116303] usb 4-5: New USB device found, idVendor=22b8, idProduct=2e63
```

and `lsusb` reports:

```
Bus 004 Device 005: ID 22b8:2e63 Motorola PCS
```

which tell me that my phone has a vendor id of 22b8 and product id 2e63.  The udev rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="22b8", MODE="0664", GROUP="android"
```

will match this device (and all motorola phones since it is not constrained by a product id) and set permissions on the USB device for this phone to:

```
crw-rw-r--+ 1 root android 189, 388 May  5 19:38 /dev/bus/usb/004/005
```

You can find your usb device to check its permissions using the usb bus and device number.  `lsusb` reported `Bus 004 Device 005` and the device path contains `.../004/005`.   As long as you can read/write to this device you will be able to use `adb` and other programs that require access to the phone.

Caveat: device naming could be slightly different on your system.  I'm running udev 215 and linux kernel 4.0.1.